# How do I map a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship in Fluent API in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

**Edited**

I have 2 tables, Nurse and Person.  Person has a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship to Nurse.  In other words some Persons in my application will also be a Nurse.  I would like to use the same primary key in both tables.  When I run my code querying the Nurse table, I end up with a "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException", and then on the inner exception: "SqlException: Invalid column name 'Person_Id'."

My Nurse model does not have a "Person_Id" field in it.  The generated query seems to have added it.  I must be missing something in my model definition, as removing "public virtual Person Person { get; set; }" makes the query generate correctly.  EF seems to get hung up on the fact that the PK is Id in the Person table, but NurseId in the Nurse table.

I've found multiple places on the internet that show you how to map this with Fluent API, but nothing that matches my case.  Because most Persons in my application are not Nurse, I don't want to have to reference the Nurse model in my Person model, which takes away the solution I keep seeing online:

```
//won't work because I am trying to no have a reference to Nurse in my Person model.  So i.Nurse below doesn't exist
modelBuilder.Entity<Nurse>().HasRequired(i => i.Person).WithOptional(i => i.Nurse)
```

The query EF generates:

```
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[NurseId] AS [NurseId], 
[Extent1].[CredentialId] AS [CredentialId], 
[Extent1].[DisciplineId] AS [DisciplineId], 
[Extent1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
[Extent1].[YearsOfService] AS [YearsOfService], 
[Extent1].[Person_Id] AS [Person_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Nurse] AS [Extent1]}
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nurse]
(
    [NurseId] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Nurse] PRIMARY KEY ([NurseId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Nurse_Person] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([Id])
)
```

And the Entities:

```
public class Person 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Nurse
{
    [Key]
    public long NurseId { get; set; }

    public long? CredentialId { get; set; }

    public long? DisciplineId { get; set; }

    public long? UnitId { get; set; }

    public int? YearsOfService { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CredentialId")]
    public virtual Credential Credential { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DisciplineId")]
    public virtual Discipline Discipline { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitId")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext() : base("ApplicationDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Nurse> Nurses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
       modelBuilder.Entity<Nurse>().HasKey(n => n.NurseId);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, or do I need to reference Nurse in my Person table and go with what I've seen online?

Comment: You say `Nurse` inherits from `Person`, but your code doesn't reflect that.

Comment: You should read about [Relationships between Entities](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that stumble across this. I found the answer [here](http://www.joaopauloseixas.com/howtodoit.net/?p=3407). The fluent api I posted was close, it should have been:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Nurse>().HasRequired(n => n.Person).WithOptional();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using PersonId has the primary key in Nurse. Try giving Nurse its own Id. It is a good idea for every table to have its own Ids. EF has issues with tables or views that do not have a unique primary key.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nurse]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] BIGINT unique NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Nurse] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Nurse_Person] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([Id])
)
```

Comment: That's what I am hoping to avoid doing, because theoretically I could end up with a person being tied to multiple Nurse records.

Comment: In that case add the key word unique to PersionId in Nurse table.[PersonId] BIGINT unique NOT NULL, I will edit my answer.